# Android show contact list in Listview

Tags: android, listview, contacts

In my android application I need to show the contact list in listview .. but when I am displaying contacts are repeating ..I am giving my code below if anyone can suggest what change I need to give please help... iam giving my code below

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


           while (c.moveToNext())
        {

                String contactName = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phNumber = c
                        .getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


                boolean retval2 = contacts1.contains(contactName);
                if (retval2 == false)
                {

                    Contact con = new Contact(c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)), c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));

                    contacts.add(con);
                    contacts1.add(contactName);
                }


            }

       listView.setAdapter(new ContactsAdapter(this, contacts));





public class Contact
{
    private String name;
    private String mobile;

    public Contact(String name, String mobile)
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMobile()
    {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile)
    {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) what is contacts object? 2) where is the adapter? 3) Contact object structure?

Comment: Probably problem is in `ContactsAdapter` class

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley I added contact class .. please check it

Comment: add the adapter and the question is ok, the problem, as @ρяσѕρєяK said, is probably there

Comment: use CursorLoader for this ... https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/c6182418fd1c387bf5b6 ... comment sms related code, uncoment phones related code ... that's it ...

Answer (score -1):

This might help removing duplicates

```
if(!contacts.contains(con))
 {
    contacts.add(con);
 }
```